# What is Nina doing?

Tags: code-geass

In episode 12, 7:43 there is a part were Nina Einstein is doing something. *Is that what I think it is?*

Possibly NSFW:  **[Link to Youtube Video](http://youtu.be/gs40WmlQhW4?t=7m43s)** ([Alternate link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ezwhZC4R-eI))

Comment: I am also wondering what she was doing there.

Comment: well, she 'loves' the class rep..

Comment: I thought the more common interpretation was that she had something of a crush on Euphemia...

Comment: It is *exactly* what you think it is

Comment: Dude. WTF, I never noticed that before.

Comment: why is this question suddenly getting attention? was there a tv rerun of code geass or something?

Comment: @Esq you don't have the rep to see it but an answer was posted and deleted, the very act of posting a new answer bumps the question to the top of the main page's list so everyone sees it

Answer (score 19, accepted):

On the [Code Geass Wikia](http://codegeass.wikia.com/wiki/Nina_Einstein#First_Season) it says

> Nina is shown masturbating to her picture in episode 12.

"Her" refers to Euphemia. Nina began to develop a crush for her back during the Japanese Liberation Front Hotel Incident when Euphie revealed her identity to the JLF to save Nina from being attacked.

Nina's crush on Euphie is almost obsessive and even what she says sometimes can be seen as innuendo to her wanting an intimate relationship. In one episode, she attempts to meet Euphie but is pinned down by the guards and Euphie once again saves her. As they talk by the fireplace, Nina says she wants "Euphie's goodness" elaborating that she wants Euphie's bodily fluid (whether she means saliva or "something else" is up to the imagination).

Now I haven't read anywhere which actually confirms what Nina is doing, but what the wiki says is widely accepted due to her obsession for Euphie, her body movements during and after the scene (including how Nina adjusts her skirt when speaking to Nunnally) and the sound effects, and there is very little else a girl would do when they have images of the object of their obsession in the dark room like that.